# Next Button that cycles back to first on Access Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been trying a couple things to create a button that navigates back to the first record you are at the last record.  I get the "can't go to specified record" error.  Here are the two styles of code I have tried for this button:

```
Private Sub Command161_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.CurrentRecord = acLast Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
        Else
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
       End If

End Sub

Private Sub Command161_Click()
With Me.Recordset
  If .AbsolutePosition = .RecordCount - 1 Then
      DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
  Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

The goal is to loop back around to the first record without allowing the user to create a new record.  I've tried this code with "allow additions" set to both yes and now, with the same result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest defining a private predicate function within your form module which returns a boolean value depending on whether or not the active form is displaying the last record in its Record Source.

Such a function might be written:

```vb
Private Function LastRecordP() As Boolean
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
            LastRecordP = Me.CurrentRecord = .RecordCount
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Your `OnClick` event handler for your button control could then be written more succinctly as:

```vb
Private Sub Command161_Click()
    If LastRecordP Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, you could allow the function to accept a Form object as an argument and evaluate such function using the `Me` keyword, e.g.:

```vb
Private Function LastRecordP(Frm As Form) As Boolean
    With Frm.RecordsetClone
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
            LastRecordP = Frm.CurrentRecord = .RecordCount
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

```vb
Private Sub Command20_Click()
    If LastRecordP(Me) Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @KyleQuigley You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!